# IP Address in ARP Cache

Tags: arp

I am learning more about networking... I am working on some Wireshark Labs and the subject is ARP. 
Screen shot of ARP Cache
[image: Windows Command ARP]
 During the lab I did an ARP Cache dump. Fired up Wireshark and went to a page. I looked again in my ARP cache. I get why that I see my router and other devices (IPs with 192.168.0.XXX). I just don't know where 224.0.0.XXX or 239.255.255.250 IP addresses are coming from. I get that the 255.255.255.255 address is my subnet(?), but the others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [multicast](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml) address space:

```
The multicast addresses are in the range
224.0.0.0 through 239.255.255.255. Address assignments are listed below.

The range of addresses between 224.0.0.0 and 224.0.0.255, inclusive,
is reserved for the use of routing protocols and other low-level
topology discovery or maintenance protocols, such as gateway discovery
and group membership reporting.  Multicast routers should not forward
any multicast datagram with destination addresses in this range,
regardless of its TTL.
```